# How to give Tkinter G.U.I button a function to create highscores? [Update]

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to learn how to input a high score function on a GUI button. 
I have a code that creates and saves highscore, but I want to implement it onto a button. 
Here's my `Highscore.py` code:

```
def get_high_score():
    # Default high score
    high_score = 0

    # Try to read the high score from a file
    try:
        high_score_file = open("high_score.txt", "r")
        high_score = int(high_score_file.read())
        high_score_file.close()
        print("The high score is", high_score)
    except IOError:
        # Error reading file, no high score
        print("There is no high score yet.")
    except ValueError:
        # There's a file there, but we don't understand the number.
        print("I'm confused. Starting with no high score.")

    return high_score


def save_high_score(new_high_score):
    try:
        # Write the file to disk
        high_score_file = open("high_score.txt", "w")
        high_score_file.write(str(new_high_score))
        high_score_file.close()
    except IOError:
        # Hm, can't write it.
        print("Unable to save the high score.")


def main():
    """ Main program is here. """
    # Get the high score
    high_score = get_high_score()

    # Get the score from the current game
    current_score = 0
    try:
        # Ask the user for his/her score
        current_score = int(input("What is your score? "))
    except ValueError:
        # Error, can't turn what they typed into a number
        print("I don't understand what you typed.")

    # See if we have a new high score
    if current_score > high_score:
        # We do! Save to disk
        print("Yea! New high score!")
        save_high_score(current_score)
    else:
        print("Better luck next time.")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
('The high score is', 121345)
What is your score? `[input]`
```

I tried to use the `Highscore.py` code and put it into another`def high_score()` function. I tried using a GUI button that runs command off `def high_score()` function but it doesn't function properly.

This is my attempt on the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def high_score():
    def get_high_score():
    # Default high score
        high_score = 0

    # Try to read the high score from a file
    try:
        high_score_file = open("high_score.txt", "r")
        high_score = int(high_score_file.read())
        high_score_file.close()
        print("The high score is", high_score)
    except IOError:
        # Error reading file, no high score
        print("There is no high score yet.")
    except ValueError:
        # There's a file there, but we don't understand the number.
        print("I'm confused. Starting with no high score.")

    return high_score


    # See if we have a new high score
    if current_score > high_score:
        # We do! Save to disk
        print("Yea! New high score!")
        save_high_score(current_score)
    else:
        print("Better luck next time.")
    def main():
        """ Main program is here. """
        # Get the high score
        high_score = get_high_score()

        # Get the score from the current game
        current_score = 0
        try:
            # Ask the user for his/her score
            current_score = int(input("What is your score? "))
        except ValueError:
            # Error, can't turn what they typed into a number
            print("I don't understand what you typed.")
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
# Make a top level Tk window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Cracker GUI v.01")
#Make button which takes highscore as a command
mega_button = tk.Button(root, text="Highscore", command=high_score)
mega_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', width=10, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()
#Lets get the show on the road
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show us how you tried creating the button that called `high_score`.

Comment: So I created a button that was supposed to launch 'the high_score' program, and it doesn't work properly or I just do not know how to do it.

Comment: I updated with my coding attempt on it. You can test it to see my error. I would appreciate it if you can give me advice and criticize my code as you see fit.